# How to pick one element from database atomically?

Tags: python, django, transactions

I have a Django application with a simple model:

```
class ThingToPick(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    filedata = models.TextField()
```

The on some view I have:

```
    exec_item = ThingToRun.objects.filter(status=0).order_by('start_date')[0]
    exec_item.status = 1
    exec_item.save()
```

I need some way to pick each `ThingToRun` from one and only one concurrent user. I know this is broken, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to build a queue-like mechanism and this is the dispatcher? Do I got this right?

Comment: @Puciek yes you got it right

Comment: Really you should use a proper task manager, ie Celery.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You mean the [Database-as-IPC anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC)? I was planning on upgrading to a MQ in the future, however for the time being this is just a proof of concept.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm also polling and hammering the DB, which is bad. I know that.

Comment: @vz0 I will have to second the celery notion, especially since it is extramly easy to implement - all you have to do is wrap your worker functions with a task decorator and you are ready to go. So while it may not be perfect for large-scale deployments, it certainly is perfect for mocking up due to how easy it is to do implement, even in existing system: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

Comment: Awesome. I don't mean to be rude, I mean you guys are right on pointing to Celery. But my question is not about MQs or task managers, is about "how to pick one element from DB atomically". That discussion belongs better to programmers.sx. Thanks.

Comment: OK, but if I understand correctly it's not "picking" that you want to be atomic, but "pick this one and mark it as in process so that no-one else picks it in the meantime", yes?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. I have a set of unassigned tasks and I want to relate this taks to at most one "processing unit", atomically, having many concurrent threads selecting elements from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do here is not just picking something, but picking something and marking it as in process so that no-one else picks it in the meantime. So the method you want is [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update):

```
exec_item = ThingToRun.objects.select_for_update().filter(status=0).order_by('start_date')[0]
exec_item.status = 1
exec_item.save()
...process exec_item ....
```

Comment: Isn't here a race condition? I dont have any transactions configured for my views.

Comment: Yes you need to do it inside a block where autocommit is off.